# Can I call a class function within a for loop?

Tags: function, class, for-loop

I'm trying to complete a homework assignment and came across an issue that has me stuck. I'm trying to call a function from a class called Dataset, that takes 4 arguments: a city (str), a month (int), a day (int), and a year (int). However, whenever I run my code, it comes up with this error message:

> TypeError: Dataset.get_temp_on_date() missing 1 required positional argument: 'year'

Here the class:

```
class Dataset(object):
"""
The collection of temperature records loaded from given csv file
"""
def __init__(self, filename):
"""
Initialize a Dataset instance, which stores the temperature records
loaded from a given csv file specified by filename.

        Args:
            filename: name of the csv file (str)
        """
        self.rawdata = {}
    
        f = open(filename, 'r')
        header = f.readline().strip().split(',')
        for line in f:
            items = line.strip().split(',')
    
            date = re.match('(\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)', items[header.index('DATE')])
            year = int(date.group(1))
            month = int(date.group(2))
            day = int(date.group(3))
    
            city = items[header.index('CITY')]
            temperature = float(items[header.index('TEMP')])
            if city not in self.rawdata:
                self.rawdata[city] = {}
            if year not in self.rawdata[city]:
                self.rawdata[city][year] = {}
            if month not in self.rawdata[city][year]:
                self.rawdata[city][year][month] = {}
            self.rawdata[city][year][month][day] = temperature
    
        f.close()
    
    
    def get_temp_on_date(self, city, month, day, year):
        """
        Get the temperature for the given city at the specified date.
   
        Returns:
            a float of the daily temperature for the specified date and city
        """
        assert city in self.rawdata, "provided city is not available"
        assert year in self.rawdata[city], "provided year {} is not available".format(year)
        assert month in self.rawdata[city][year], "provided month is not available"
        assert day in self.rawdata[city][year][month], "provided day is not available"
        return self.rawdata[city][year][month][day]
```

And here is where I try to call get_temp_on_date:

```
year_list = list(range(1961,2017))
year_array = np.array(year_list)
temps = np.zeros(len(year_array))

for i in range(1961,2017):
    temps[i-1961] = Dataset.get_temp_on_date("PHOENIX", 12, 1, i)
```

I'm not sure how to fix this issue, but I'm assuming that it's something minor.

Comment: You need to create an instance of the `Dataset`.

Comment: To narrow your audience to those that can answer, you should tag this with the programming language used